# How to disable copy in Github pages?

Tags: github-pages

I want to disable copy paste on my webpage hosted on Github pages. I understand that it requires a snippet of code. I do not understand how I can accomplish that on my GitHub webpage.

Comment: Do you mean that you want no one to copy your website design and data?

Comment: Note: you can, but that won't really prevent copy: https://www.manjemedia.com/7-ways-to-copy-content-from-a-website-with-disabled-text-selection-and-right-clicking/